# detect compromised oauth consumer key/secret?

Tags: android, oauth, consumer

I am developing an android app levering on google services using oauth. I wanna know if there are any methods of detecting if my consumer key/secret have been compromised so that i can take action if needed?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you deploy your app your key/secret have been compromised. Due to the fact that eventually you must transmit it as a string so any attempts to hide either are simply futile efforts in obfuscation. There's really no way around it.

Comment: thx for the reply.. but i am asking for a method to DETECT if it has been compromised..

Comment: And I'm telling you that your line of thinking is flawed. Keys are compromised the moment they are available in the wild.

Comment: There is a difference between compromised (in a client accessible location) and maliciously compromised (someone has retrieved the secret and is actively using it). The first is a fact of life, the latter is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: yup obviously i meant maliciously being compromised o.0 .. now that the doubts have been cleared.. does anyone have an answer?